# Jenkins Cannot Change Working Directory: "cd: can't cd to directory" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins-pipeline, devops, cicd

I'm currently working on setting up a Jenkins pipeline for my project, and I'm encountering an issue where Jenkins fails to change its working directory. Here are the details of my setup and the problem I'm facing:

**Problem**:
Jenkins is configured to build a Docker image for my Django project. I have a simple shell script in my Jenkins job that attempts to change the working directory to my project directory and build the Docker image. However, I'm encountering the following error:

cd /home/ubuntu/myproject/Django-ToDo-CICD
/bin/sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/ubuntu/myproject/Django-ToDo-CICD

[jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFsKo.jpg)

[output build fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcKVu.jpg)

**Additional Information**:

- The project directory `/home/ubuntu/myproject/Django-ToDo-CICD` exists and has appropriate permissions.
- The Jenkins job is running as the `jenkins` user, which has read and execute permissions on the directory.
- I'm using absolute paths in my Jenkins job to avoid issues related to relative paths.

**Questions**:

1. Why is Jenkins unable to change its working directory to the specified path?
2. Are there any Jenkins user-specific configurations that might be affecting the working directory change?
3. What can I check or modify in my Jenkins setup to resolve this issue?
4. Are there any Jenkins plugins or security settings that might be causing this problem?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `jenkins user, which has read and execute permissions on the directory` but does it have permission on all directories in the path? `/home/ubuntu` is probably exclusive to `ubuntu` user.

Answer (score 1):

- Ensure that the directory `/home/ubuntu/myproject/Django-ToDo-CICD` exists on the Jenkins agent where the job is running.
- Make sure that the Jenkins user has the necessary permissions to access the specified directory. If the Jenkins user doesn't have permission, you can either grant the required permissions or adjust the ownership of the directory.
- Instead of relying on changing the working directory, you can provide the full path to your script
- Jenkins sets up a workspace for each job. You can leverage this by using the `${WORKSPACE}` environment variable in your build step. This ensures that Jenkins always uses the correct workspace for the job.:
  `cd ${WORKSPACE}/Django-ToDo-CICD`